# Problema con el bucle For

Tags: python

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio sencillo de Python, la idea es crear una función que sume los enteros de una lista. El problema es que a la hora correr mi función el "for" omite algunos elementos de la lista y no tengo idea de por qué, nunca me había pasado. Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
def simplearraysum(ar):
    sum = 0
    for number in ar:
        sum = sum + number
        ar.remove(number)
    return sum


list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11]

print(simplearraysum(list))
```

El output es 14, cuando debería ser 31.

Comment: la instrucción `ar.remove(number)` sobra

Comment: ¿por qué vas eliminando elementos de la lista a medida que los sumas? Aparte de que no veo ninguna razón para ello (la función no debería alterar la lista que está sumando), el hacerlo dentro de un bucle hace que éste no extraiga todos sus elementos correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que al usar la función `remove()` corres los elementos de la lista de lugar (hacia la izquierda), y el `for` continúa iterando por donde se quedó. Para que veas el funcionamiento interno puedes ver este código:

```
def simplearraysum(ar): 
    sum = 0
    for i, number in enumerate (ar):
        print(str(i)+": "+str(number))
        sum = sum + number
        ar.remove(number) 
    return sum 

list = [1,2,3,4,10,11]
print(simplearraysum(list))
```

La salida es:

> 0: 1 1: 3 2: 10 14
>
> [Program finished]

Si realmente necesitas ir eliminando los elementos de la lista puedes hacerlo así:

```
def simplearraysum(ar): 
    sum = 0
    for number in range(len(ar)):
        sum = sum + ar[0]
        ar.remove(ar[0]) 
    return sum 

list = [1,2,3,4,10,11]
print(simplearraysum(list))
```

La salida es:

> 31
>
> [Program finished]

Comment: Nunca ha sido buena idea alterar una lista mientras se itera entre sus elementos. Aún así, también podrías usar el método `.pop(0)` que combina la extracción del primer elemento y su borrado de la lista.